# Coordinates - See if given X, Y is inside the square area, if not, find the closest position

Tags: java, coordinates

So we have a square area out of coordinates,

bottomX, bottomY, topX, topY, see the screenshot below of how I took it:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/e23cd17fad3556dcd8ba04daa1f93e50.png))</sub>

I defined it like this: `3093, 3528, 3083, 3538`

Now, we want to check if the given X, Y coordinates of the player are inside the square, to do that we do this:

```
public boolean inArea(int x, int y) {
    return (x <= getBottomX() && x >= getUpperX() && y >= getBottomY() && y <= getUpperY());
}

inArea(X, Y);
```

Now, if the player is not in the area, we want to use the selected waypoint's coordinates he wanted to go to & manipulate so it will find the closest X, Y that are inside the square.

Imagine we have the following square:

```
bottomX: -10
bottomY: -10
topX: 10
topY: 10
```

Player went to X 13, y -16

The system will move the player to: `X 10, Y -10`

Same here, player is located at `3084, 3487`, if he moves up to `3090, 3487`, the system will move him to `X 3087 y 3487` cause he got out of the Y.

How can I do that?

that's my attempt:

```
            if (pathX >= bottomX && pathX > upperX) {
                    pathX -= (pathX - upperX);
            }   
            if (pathX < bottomX && pathX >= upperX) {
                c.pathX -= (pathX - bottomX);
            }   
            if (pathY >= bottomY && pathY > upperY) {
                pathY -= (pathY - bottomY);
            }   
            if (pathY < bottomY && pathY >= upperY) {
                pathY -= (pathY - upperY);
            }
```

But it doesn't really work, what it does is, if my Y is not inside, it will go to the corner of right side bottom, it just doesn't work smoothly.

What did I do wrong?

```
        Coordinate map = getMap().currentMap;
        int bottomX = map.getBottomX();
        int bottomY = map.getBottomY();
        int upperX = map.getUpperX();
        int upperY = map.getUpperY();
        if (pathX <= bottomX && pathX >= upperX && pathY >= bottomY && pathY <= upperY) {
            walkTo(pathX, pathY);
            return;
        }
        else {

            if (pathX < bottomX) {
                pathX = bottomX;
            } else if (pathX > upperX) {
                pathX = upperX;
            }

            if (pathY < bottomY) {
                pathY = bottomY;
            } else if (pathY > upperY) {
                pathY = upperY;
            }

            walkTo(pathX, pathY);
        }
```

Comment: Y: 3487 is not even close to the box given, so if player moves to Y: 3490, he's actually moving closer to the box, so shouldn't that be allowed?

Comment: @t0mppa Nope, above 3487, it just gets out of the area. see this http://gyazo.com/29477c56188adcbe58438cb1bd4e35fd

Comment: But 3487 is actually 41 points below the area to begin with, so he's not moving away, but towards it?

Comment: Wait I've made an accident, I mean 3087 to 3090 = out, not the Y coord, I fixed.

Comment: Y coordinate is still outside of the area, while both 3087 and 3090 are inside the area, so that doesn't make sense either. Something like: 3083,3530 -> 3083,3525 would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the `if` clauses make sense?

You're checking if `pathX` is equal or greater than `bottomX` and at the same time greater than `upperX`. If the latter is true, former is always true as well, thus the former is a redundant check.

Conversely, how can `pathX` ever be both less than `bottomX` and equal or greater than `upperX`? If `x` is less than `-10` and equal or greater than `10`, things are royally farked up.

*** EDIT ***

If you don't want to let the player get out of the area, do it like this:

```
if (pathX > bottomX) {
  pathX = bottomX;
} else if (pathX < upperX) {
  pathX = upperX;
}

if (pathY < bottomY) {
  pathY = bottomY;
} else if (pathY > upperY) {
  pathY = upperY;
}
```

Comment: Read my edit, probably makes more sense now since I accidently showed Y instead of X in the example

Comment: I'm talking about the code snippet at the end of your post, where you have those four `if` clauses.

Comment: Oh, nope I am not really sure about the if clauses, I just tried something.

Comment: Basically, if I walk to top, it will take me to the right top corner, if i walk to the  right side, it will take me to left side.

Ill give another example probably more clear:

I am standing at X 3088 Y 3486 I walked to 3088 3488, the system will take me back to 3088 3487, but your code takes me to 3090, 3487

Comment: Ah, I see. `bottomX` is a larger number than `upperX`, while `bottomY` is a smaller number than `upperY`. The names were throwing me off.

Comment: See the newest edit, I had the X's wrong way around, because of the names.